# WordPress regex not working as expected

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I need to put a string like `user-profile/id=3` into regex form. I tried `'user-profile/id=\d+$'`  and also `'user-profile/([a-z][.][0-9]+)/?$'`, but none of them are working. What is the correct way?

Comment: What you want to get from this string with regex?

Comment: I just want to extract the `id=3` part.

Comment: In that case I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: You really do not want a simple `explode("/", $s)[1]` approach? I have an impression your string is always in the format as above, you do not need a regex. See https://ideone.com/2QFYks

Comment: Correct, it will always be in that format. I'm willing to try that approach as well, I'm very open lol. Thank you for all these helpful suggestions.

Comment: I added 2 non-regex solutions for you. I hope they will be useful.

Comment: Great stuff! i dont even need a regex, lol. thanks @WiktorStribiżew  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your string is always in the format as above, you do not need a regex. Use a mere [**`explode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
explode("/", $s)[1]
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/2QFYks).

Another  non-regex approach: use [**`strstr`**](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.strstr.php) to get the substring after and including `/`, and then get the [**`substr`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)ing from the 1 char:

```
substr(strstr($s, "/"),1);
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/yN4X8Z)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you aren't escaping the `/` character with a backslash.

Another problem you could face immediately after solving that one, is that you are using the `$` character, which means end of line. If there are more characters afterwards, even just a single space, then it won't match.

If you try:

```
user-profile\/(id=\d+)
```

You'll probably find that it matches just fine. The brackets I added in will capture `id=3` in capture group #1.

Comment: It is not necessary to escape `/` in a regex. Try `'~user-profile/(id=\d+)~'`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract `id=3` I recommend to use `preg_replace`. Like:

```
$str = 'user-profile/id=3';
$after_preg = preg_replace('/user-profile\//', '', $str);
echo $after_preg;
```

If you want to get just a number it can be as follows:

```
$str = 'user-profile/id=3';
$after_preg = preg_replace('/user-profile\/id=/', '', $str);
echo $after_preg;
```

More about it you can read in [PHP Manual: preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

If you want to check if you string is like `user-profile/id=3` you can use regex:

```
user-profile\/id=\d*
```